# Static files uploaded on s3 won't show locally

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I just uploaded my statics on S3 and CloudFront. `python manage.py collectstatic` succeeded.
I know the correct behavior now would be that when i run my app locally, all the statics would be running from S3 as the static url had been changed. But none of this happens. 
I've tried running `python manage.py runserver --nostatic` : the server runs but all my assets are gone locally (even when i run this command without `--nostatic`).

Here is my `settings.py` :

```
import os
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
import boto3

...

# AWS CloudFront
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'us-east-2'  # e.g. us-east-2
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*******'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*******'
AWS_S3_HOST = 's3-us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=1209600, no-transform'
}

# static
BUCKET_STATIC_NAME = '*******'
CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN = '*******.cloudfront.net'

# media
BUCKET_MEDIA_NAME = '*******'
CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN = '*******.cloudfront.net'

# storage
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'elef.custom_storage.MediaS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'elef.custom_storage.CachedStaticS3BotoStorage'

MEDIA_URL = 'https://%s/' % CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN
STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/' % CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN

AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
```

I also have a `custom_storage.py` :

```
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage, SpooledTemporaryFile
import boto3
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import CachedFilesMixin


class CachedStaticS3BotoStorage(CachedFilesMixin, S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    S3BotoStorage backend which also saves a hashed copies of the files it saves.
    """
    bucket_name = settings.BUCKET_STATIC_NAME
    custom_domain = settings.CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN

    def _save_content(self, obj, content, parameters):
        content.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
        content_autoclose = SpooledTemporaryFile()
        content_autoclose.write(content.read())
        super(CachedStaticS3BotoStorage, self)._save_content(obj, content_autoclose, parameters)

        if not content_autoclose.closed:
            content_autoclose.close()


class MediaS3BotoStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    """
    S3BotoStorage backend for media files.
    """
    bucket_name = settings.BUCKET_MEDIA_NAME
    custom_domain = settings.CLOUDFRONT_MEDIA_DOMAIN
```

Here is the server traceback when running `python manage.py runserver` (or `python manage.py runserver --nostatic`):

```
^C(*****) djeustinezzz:***** justine_dev$ python manage.py runserver --nostatic
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

You have 15 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.

February 11, 2019 - 11:28:11
Django version 2.1.5, using settings 'elefmarket.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[11/Feb/2019 11:28:16] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 5775
Not Found: /static/images/logos/logo_bronze_2.png
[11/Feb/2019 11:28:16] "GET /static/images/logos/logo_bronze_2.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3082
Not Found: /static/images/pictos/btc-5.png
[11/Feb/2019 11:28:16] "GET /static/images/pictos/btc-5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3061
Not Found: /static/images/pictos/margin-5.png
Not Found: /static/images/pictos/aws.png
[11/Feb/2019 11:28:16] "GET /static/images/pictos/aws.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3055
[11/Feb/2019 11:28:16] "GET /static/images/pictos/margin-5.png HTTP/1.1" 404 3070
```

Don't mind the unapplied migrations, i'm using a nosql database.

Also, here is how i call statics in `home.html`:

```
{% load static %}
{% load i18n %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>******</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="static/images/logos/elef.png"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/home.css' %}">
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, if it can help others.
I had public settings not set correctly in the S3 console. The access was denied, so my server couldn't access the statics. 
You'll need to checks the permissions:
`Amazon S3` > `your-bucket` > `permissions` > `public access settings` and then, edit the settings as you wish.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You've set MEDIA_URL to point to your S3 domain, but not STATIC_URL.

Comment: sorry i think i did. i forgot this line on `settings.py`: `STATIC_URL = 'https://%s/' % CLOUDFRONT_STATIC_DOMAIN`. i will edit my question

Comment: OK. Can you show how you are referencing those assets in your template?

Comment: just did. i hope this is what you wanted

Comment: You're not consistently using the `{% static %}` tag; you need to use it for all static files.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Instead of doing `href="static/whatever.png"` make sure you do `href="{% static "whatever.png" %}"`.